# NoneType object is not callable when adding saved FK

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm getting the error message **'NoneType' object is not callable** when trying to save `Campaign`. In Django does it mean once I have saved my object `SingleVoucherReward()` I don't have access to it and cannot assign it to my Campaign object?

```
single_voucher_reward = SingleVoucherReward()
single_voucher_reward.description = "test"
single_voucher_reward.save()

Campaign.participant_reward(single_voucher_reward)
Campaign.save()
```

Model:

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, help_text="Give your campaign a name i.e Xmas Offer")

    participant_reward_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                                                        editable=False,
                                                        related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_as_participant',
                                                        )
    participant_reward_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    participant_reward = generic.GenericForeignKey('participant_reward_content_type', 'participant_reward_object_id')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign things to the class, not the instance of the class. Try:

```
campaign = Campaign()
campaign.participant_reward = single_voucher_reward
campaign.save()
```

or

```
campaign = Campaign(participant_reward = single_voucher_reward)
campaign.save()
```